# Why service classes are not autowired?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'll try to develop simple web service.
In order to make test data, i create test class.
However, in this class, there is error that service classes are not autowired.
help me.
Why it is not autoried?

This is error message.

```html
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
 at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
 at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
 at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
 at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
 at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
 at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
 at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
 at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
 at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
 at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
 at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
 ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
 ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
 at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.<init>(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.java:53)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:451)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c4ca4a4e.CGLIB$defaultServletHandlerMapping$26(<generated>)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c4ca4a4e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3fa44495.invoke(<generated>)
 at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:355)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c4ca4a4e.defaultServletHandlerMapping(<generated>)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
 ... 43 more
```

This is my test class.

```html
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppInitializer.class)
public class createTestData {
 @Autowired
 private UserService userService;
 
 @Autowired
 private ReadabilityService readabilityService;
 
 @Test
 @Transactional
 public void createTestData()
 {
  .....
  testData.setUser(userService.findByUsername("test1"));
  .....
 }
}
```

This is configuration class.

```html
package com.websystique.springmvc.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.PathMatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

import com.websystique.springmvc.service.UserService;



@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.websystique.springmvc")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
 
 
 /**
     * Configure ViewResolvers to deliver preferred views.
     */
 @Override
 public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
  InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
  viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
  viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
  viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
  registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
 }
 
 /**
     * Configure ResourceHandlers to serve static resources like CSS/ Javascript etc...
     */
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }
    
    /**
     * Configure Converter to be used.
     * In our example, we need a converter to convert string values[Roles] to UserProfiles in newUser.jsp
     */
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    }
 

    /**
     * Configure MessageSource to lookup any validation/error message in internationalized property files
     */
    @Bean
 public MessageSource messageSource() {
     ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
     messageSource.setBasename("messages");
     return messageSource;
 }
    
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @Bean
    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        filter.setForceEncoding(true);
        return filter;
    }
    
    /**Optional. It's only required when handling '.' in @PathVariables which otherwise ignore everything after last '.' in @PathVaidables argument.
     * It's a known bug in Spring [https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6164], still present in Spring 4.1.7.
     * This is a workaround for this issue.
     */
    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer matcher) {
        matcher.setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(true);
    }
}
```

help me

Comment: Have you read the stacktrace? Which indicates you are trying to load web based classes in a now web based test. Read [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#__webappconfiguration) on how to be able to test web based things.

Comment: Your test don't know about your configuration cause you didn't list it in ContextConfiguration

Comment: Thank you. so much. i forgot this.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read the stacktrace? Which indicates you are trying to load web based classes in a now web based test. Read the documentation on how to be able to test web based things